# (C++) How to use OpenBlas libraries with C++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openblas

Sorry if this all seems too simple but I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use the OpenBlas libraries in my C++ IDE "CodeBlocks" on Windows. More specifically, I'm want to use the matrix-vector multiplication and solving of a tri-diagonal matrix system libraries. I've downloaded the files at the bottom of the page on the OpenBlas site. I'm not sure how I would even start, as there are little/no resources online for beginners such as myself. What libraries do I need to include in my .cpp file preamble, have I even downloaded the correct set of files, which files do I need to include in my working directory, etc?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've downloaded the pre-built files as recommended and followed every step in the link below.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

I have also included #include "cblas.h" in the preamble of my .cpp file but I am getting a **undefined reference to 'cblas_XXXXX'** error in my build messages. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the pre-built winodws library

https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.15/OpenBLAS-v0.2.15-Win64-int32.zip/download